# Open3D-ML and pytorch

Tags: pytorch, open3d

I’m currently trying to work with open3d ML and Pytorch. I followed the installation guide given in the Open3D-ML github. However when I try to import open3d.ml.torch it sends me the following error : `Exception: Open3D was not built with PyTorch support!`

I’m working with

```
python 3.8
open3d 0.12.0
pytorch 1.6.0
cuda 10.1
Windows 10
```

Do you have any idea of where that error comes from ?

Answer (score 1):

It does not support for Windows at the moment. You can install Ubuntu on WSL (Window Subsystem for Linux) on Windows OS, and install open3d-ml on ubuntu.

Comment: I have installed WSL2 on windows.  I am using VS Code with WSL extension and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the output of the following commands on Windows Terminal (or PowerShell) is:

- `wsl cat /proc/version`

  ```
  Linux version 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2
  ```
- `wsl --list`

  ```
  Ubuntu-20.04 (Standard)
  ```
- `wsl -l -v`

  ```
  Ubuntu-20.04    Running         2
  ```

In my experience, Open3D-ML with CUDA only works if you are a Windows Insider, updated the WSL kernel correctly, and you are using Ubuntu in WSL.

Also, check if the folder `/usr/lib/wsl/lib` exists. If not, then CUDA won't work in WSL.